# Why C builds small programs faster than Go or D?

Tags: c, performance, go, build, d

Go and D advertised to have incredibly fast compilers.
Due to a modern design of the language itself with concurrent single-pass parsing in mind.

With an understanding that most of the build time wasted in linking phase. I wonder why gcc still faster on small programs.

**C**

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main() {
    printf("Hello\n");
}
```

```
$ time gcc hello.c
real    0m0.724s
user    0m0.030s
sys     0m0.046s
```

**D**

Idiomatic

```
import std.stdio;
void main() {
    writeln("Hello\n");
}
```

```
$ time dmd hello.d

real    0m1.620s
user    0m0.047s
sys     0m0.015s
```

With hacks

```
import core.stdc.stdio;
void main() {
    printf("Hello\n");
}
```

```
$ time dmd hello.d
real    0m1.593s
user    0m0.061s
sys     0m0.000s

$ time dmd -c hello.d
real    0m1.203s
user    0m0.030s
sys     0m0.031s
```

**Go**

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello.")
}
```

```
$ time go build hello.go
real    0m2.109s
user    0m0.016s
sys     0m0.031s
```

**Java**

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello.");
    }
}
```

```
$ time javac Hello.java
real    0m1.500s
user    0m0.031s
sys     0m0.031s
```

Comment: What exact commands are you running to time it for each one?

Comment: And to be fair, the Go compiler (and probably the D one too) isn't targeted at being fast for small programs… while the speed is important even for small programs, that's the speed for large programs with lots of dependencies that is the real goal.

Comment: I actually suspect what is going on here has to do with standard libraries. Line by line, D compiles fastest of all of them. But a typical D hello world program also imports almost 100,000 lines of code from the standard library, so it has a way of performing badly on small tests relative to C (unless you compensate, e.g. call printf instead of writef to avoid the D stdlib), but the speed becomes more apparent in bigger programs. (unless you hit one of the unoptimized CTFE paths, lol)

Comment: In addition to the previous comments : compiling very small programs is not a valid method for mesuring compilation time. In that case the overhead for loading and initializing the compiler is far longer than the actual compile time. You should do the comparision with a much larger program, and the compile time results will be quite different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Running `compiler filename` actually still runs the linker and may copy in a good amount of the standard library to the generated executable (especially hurting D and Go, which static link their language runtimes by default for better compatibility).

Given this trivial D hello world:

```
import std.stdio;
void main() { writeln("hello world"); }
```

Let me show you some timings on my computer:

```
$ time dmd hello.d

real    0m0.204s
user    0m0.177s
sys     0m0.025s
```

Contrast to skipping the link step with `-c`, which means "compile, do not link":

```
$ time dmd -c hello.d

real    0m0.054s
user    0m0.048s
sys     0m0.006s
```

Cuts down the time to about 1/4 the first run - in this small program, nearly 3/4 of the compile time is actually linking.

Now, let me modify the program a bit:

```
import core.stdc.stdio;
void main() { printf("hello world\n"); }

$ time dmd -c hello.d

real    0m0.017s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.001s
```

Cut in half by using printf instead of writeln! I'll come back to this.

And, just for comparison's sake, compile+link:

```
$ time dmd hello.d

real    0m0.099s
user    0m0.083s
sys     0m0.014s
```

This gives us an idea of what's going on:

- the linker eats a good chunk of time. Using `-c` removes it from the equation.
- parsing the standard library also takes a good chunk of time. Using just the C function instead of the D lib cuts that out and gives a more apples-to-apples look.
- But, using the stdlib is important to see the scalability thing.

What D (and I presume, Go, but I don't know much about them) aims to do is reduce the  time to compile medium to large programs. Small programs are already fast - waiting for a fraction of a second (or perhaps one or two on slower computers, the one I'm on now has a nice SSD on it which will speed this up, running the same command on a spinning hard disk about doubles the time!) for a small build isn't a big deal.

Waiting several *minutes* for a big build is a problem though. If we can cut that down to several seconds, it is a major win.

The time to compile 100,000 lines is more important than the time to compile 10. So init times aren't really important. Link times matter, but there's not much the compiler itself does about that (the linker is a separate program written by separate teams, though there are efforts to improve that too elsewhere).

So the time D takes to build including the standard library is where it gets impressive. Slower than a C hello world (because the C compiler does less work with the smaller lib), but you already see benefits over a C++ hello world, which is slower per line and also tends to have more work to do on each build (parsing #includes, etc).

A good compiler benchmark would want to isolate these issues and test scalability more than small programs. Though D does *very* well on small programs too if you run the test right to ensure a fair comparison.

Comment: Go was designed for scalably fast compilation of programs (Google source tree scale) during development in comparison to C++ programs.

Comment: To expand on what @peterSO stated, here's [the Rob Pike's talk](http://talks.golang.org/2012/splash.article) on which "pain points" experienced by software engeneers at Google drove the Go creators to create this language and its approach to compilation (and packages).

Comment: I don't understand why using D's standard library or including linking phase is not fair. `gcc` spits out executable so contenders should too. It's nice to have fast compiler but if overall build is slow it doesn't matter. If C wins by doing less work, why D doing more work than necessary?

Comment: @user2418306, C only wins on small programs which doesn't matter anyway. There's no point in competing in that. Go and D are more complex languages with big runtimes so they're obviously slower when most of the build time is spent linking the runtime. You could also take assembly and beat C build times but that's also pointless. But when you have a large project runtime linking is nothing compared to compiling and linking actual application code. C/C++ might take minutes, hours (some take a whole day) to build where's Go and D will take a couple of seconds.

Comment: @user2418306 it is just important to understand what you are measuring. It is true that 100,000 lines of D (hello world + stdio.d + dependencies) compiles slower than 1,000 lines of C (hello world + stdio.h). But if you compare 100k lines of D to 100k lines of C, then you can see the difference.

Comment: @creker Is there some measurable boundary (in LOC) when D will start to have faster build times than C?

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe AFAIK `import` in D don't copy-paste the code as `#include` does. Why are you repeatedly saying that D must recompile it's huge `stdlib`?

Comment: `import` still reads the file to parse the declarations and instantiate any templates that are necessary. This is much faster than `include` in C and a file being imported multiple times does not need to be reparsed (unlike `include`) but it does need to read it once. Again, this is something that is most seen at scale: in both cases, it will be parsed at least once, but in D, it is done only once per compiler instantiation and in C it may be done several times. `std.stdio` goes through much of the lib because of the format string support and file functionality being deep.